# Precompiled headers aren't being used, GCC

Tags: c, gcc, precompiled-headers

I'm following exactly how it says in the official docs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html), and I cannot find any results on Google whatsoever about precompiled headers not working.
I'm compiling with `gcc main.c -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image`, and I've compiled the headers with `gcc <headername>`. I've used -H to check if the PCHs are being used and they aren't, I am also using about 45 headers, and there's a clear difference in compile times when not using headers.

Example:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "header.h"

int main() {

    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// header.h
char* string = "Hello World!";
```

Compiled with `gcc -H main.c`
it gives the same output after compiling the header with `gcc header.h`
Output:

```
. /usr/include/stdio.h
.. /usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h
... /usr/include/features.h
.... /usr/include/features-time64.h
..... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
..... /usr/include/bits/timesize.h
...... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
.... /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
..... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
..... /usr/include/bits/long-double.h
.... /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h
..... /usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/include/stddef.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/include/stdarg.h
.. /usr/include/bits/types.h
... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
... /usr/include/bits/timesize.h
.... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
... /usr/include/bits/typesizes.h
... /usr/include/bits/time64.h
.. /usr/include/bits/types/__fpos_t.h
... /usr/include/bits/types/__mbstate_t.h
.. /usr/include/bits/types/__fpos64_t.h
.. /usr/include/bits/types/__FILE.h
.. /usr/include/bits/types/FILE.h
.. /usr/include/bits/types/struct_FILE.h
.. /usr/include/bits/types/cookie_io_functions_t.h
.. /usr/include/bits/stdio_lim.h
.. /usr/include/bits/floatn.h
... /usr/include/bits/floatn-common.h
.... /usr/include/bits/long-double.h
. header.h
Multiple include guards may be useful for:
/usr/include/bits/libc-header-start.h
/usr/include/bits/time64.h
/usr/include/bits/typesizes.h
/usr/include/features-time64.h
/usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.1/include/stddef.h
header.h
```

Comment: What is the name of the header file? Do you have the precompiled file generated from your header file (the `.gch` file), in the same directory as the original header file? How do you include the header file?

Comment: "…when not using headers" — did you mean "when not using pre-compiled headers"?  If you don't use headers at all, your code is unlikely to compile at all.

Comment: Also note that the documentation you link to clearly states that "Only one precompiled header can be used in a particular compilation."

Comment: With all this said, precompiled headers makes most sense when you have a so-called "god" header file, a header file which includes everything ever needed by any part of the program. This is usually not a good pattern, a source file should include only the header files it really needs, and no more. If you include lots of unnecessary header files, precompiled or not, then you're wasting your time. And for small projects, you won't really save anything at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes the precompiled headers have the correct names and are in the correct directory, and I missed that part in the documentation. I do have one header that includes all the others though, and all of the headers are 100% necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The code was modified to not use any.

Comment: Just tried only precompiling one header out of the 'god' header, still uses the original.

Comment: Please come up with a minimal, reproducible example that illustrates your problem - in this case some simple `main.c` file, a header which you want to precompile and _all_ instructions you use to build the final executable.

Comment: @Cubic I added an example to my question

Comment: Also, make sure that if you're on macOS, you're actually using `gcc`. The default developer tools on macOS "helpfully" includes a `clang` executable that's _called_ gcc, but it still is and works like `clang` (which has its own implementation of precompiled headers).

Comment: @Cubic I'm on Arch (btw)

Comment: @DinoNuggies as the docs says "A precompiled header cannot be used once the first C token is seen." ,but you include <stdio.h> before your "header.h", <stdio.h> contains lots of C tokens. So try include "header.h" before stdio.h. Or even better, make "header.h" include stdio.h so you get the advantage of precompiling stdio.h. Note also your "header.h" contains definitions, not just declarations, which may lead you to issues in bigger projects.

Comment: @nos There it is! There's the magic fix! Thank you!

Comment: @nos If you make an answer I'll mark it as the solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs says

> A precompiled header cannot be used once the first C token is seen."

However by including `<stdio.h>` before your `"header.h"`, `<stdio.h>` contains lots of C tokens, and thus the precompiled header isn't used.

Try include `"header.h"` before `<stdio.h`. Or even better, make `"header.h"` include `<stdio.h>` so you get the advantage of precompiling `stdio.h`.

Note also your "header.h" contains definitions, not just declarations, which may lead you to issues in bigger projects.